# not to return to Dialog when another Dialog is open

Tags: java, swing, parent, jdialog, modality

I'm showing up a Dialog from a JFrame, but when I click outside the dialog, the dialog gets hidden. It's supposed to the dialog won't let you do nothing unless you close it right?

This is my code:

The Dialog calling from First Dialog:

```
JProductStocking jps = JProductStocking.getProductStoking(JPanelTicket.this, oApp);
jps.setVisible(true);
```

And this is the JDIalog called:

```
public class JProductStocking extends javax.swing.JDialog implements BeanFactoryApp{
public JProductStocking(Component parent, boolean modal) {
        //super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();

    }

public static JProductStocking getProductStoking(Component parent, AppView app) {
        Window window = getWindow(parent);

        JProductStocking myMsg;
        if (window instanceof JFrame) { 
            myMsg = new JProductStocking((Frame) window, true);
        } else {
            myMsg = new JProductStocking((Dialog) window, true);
        }
        myMsg.init(app, parent);
        myMsg.applyComponentOrientation(parent.getComponentOrientation());
        return myMsg;
    }

     private static Window getWindow(Component parent) {
        if (parent == null) {
            return new JFrame();
        } else if (parent instanceof JFrame || parent instanceof Dialog) {
            return (Window) parent;
        } else {
            return getWindow(parent.getParent());
        }
    }

    public void init(AppView app, Component parent) {
        oApp = app;
       // m_dlSales = (DataLogicSales) app.getBean("com.openbravo.pos.forms.DataLogicSales");
        initComponents();
        ProductList = new ArrayList();
        this.setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(parent);

    }
}
```

Im not calling the jDialog well? or what im doing wrong?

Comment: You are not passing any parent `Window` to `JDialog’s` constructor so it can’t know which parent to block. It should hit your eye as you have made the `//super(parent, modal);` comment in the constructor…

Comment: @Holger I dont know how i can forget that, THANKS!
Post it like an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: @Holger Providing a parent will only tell the dialog to remain on top of it if I am not mistaken. It won't prevent the user from interacting with any visible portion of the parent. For that, the dialog must be modal.

Comment: @schmop: yes, but it’s still the same problem: the desired constructor was not called. Whether the parent is relevant to blocking depends on the modality type.

Comment: @user3480792 use local variable for JFrame, create only one JDialog, reuse this Object for another action,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not pass the parent `Window` and no `modal` flag  to the `JDialog`’s constructor so the default behavior of modeless was used. Note that besides that your code is unnecessary complicated.

Since Java 6 you can pass a `Window` to a `Dialog`’s constructor and it is allowed to be `null` so it is fail-safe. Combined with the existing method [`SwingUtilities.windowForComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#windowForComponent%28java.awt.Component%29) the entire code may look like:

```
public class JProductStocking extends javax.swing.JDialog
  implements BeanFactoryApp {

  public JProductStocking(Component parent, Dialog.ModalityType modality) {
    super(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(parent), modality);
    initComponents();
  }
// …
```

Note that with the Java 6 [`Dialog.ModalityType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html) you can configure a `Dialog` to block all other application’s windows  besides the children of this dialog (`APPLICATION_MODAL`) or to block the dialog’s parents and their children only (`DOCUMENT_MODAL`). This provides much more control than the simple `modal` flag.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you are looking for is called a "modal" dialog. You must pass 'true' to the dialog constructor:

```
public JProductStocking() {
        super((Frame)null, true); //better to pass an actual Frame, Window or Dialog object as a parent
        initComponents();

    }
```